# Wrap phrases in .NET

Tags: c#, regex, string

Is there any method in .net that wraps phrases given a maximum length for each line?

Example:

```
Phrase: The quick red fox jumps over the lazy cat
Length: 20
```

Result:

```
The quick red fox
jumps over the lazy
cat
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built in method for that. You can use a regular expression:

```
string text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
int minLength = 1;
int maxLength = 20;
MatchCollection lines = Regex.Matches(text, "(.{"+minLength.ToString()+","+maxLength.ToString()+"})(?: |$)|([^ ]{"+maxLength.ToString()+"})");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match line in lines) builder.AppendLine(line.Value);
text = builder.ToString();
```

Note: I corrected [the pangram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog).

Comment: @gt: If you concat strings with numbers, the numbers will be boxed and Concat(object[]) is called instead of Concat(string[]). (I missed one ToString, so I have added it.)

Answer (score 0):

The code in this article returns a list of lines, but you should be able to easily adapt it.

**C# Wrapping text using split and List<>**

http://bryan.reynoldslive.com/post/Wrapping-string-data.aspx